# Why use a -2 index in numpy's expand_dims

Tags: python, numpy, reshape

I am reviewing someone else's code (which uses numpy 1.16.3), and found a puzzling line, with a `-2` as the axis for expansion in `expand_dims`:

```
result = [np.expand_dims(v != 0, -2) for v in vecs]
```

Looking into the docs, I found this note:

```
Note

Previous to NumPy 1.13.0, neither axis < -a.ndim - 1 nor axis > a.ndim raised errors or put the new axis where documented. Those axis values are now deprecated and will raise an AxisError in the future.
```

which makes me think that the `-2` would simply make `expand_dims` to do nothing.
Is this the case? If so, why even use it in the code? Is it just a way to wrap the logical evaluation `v != 0`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you pass a negative `axis` value to `numpy.expand_dims`, the new axis will be placed in that position in the new array's shape. For example,

```
In [1]: import numpy

In [2]: x = numpy.zeros((3, 4, 5))

In [3]: numpy.expand_dims(x, -2).shape
Out[3]: (3, 4, 1, 5)
```

Here, the new axis is placed at index -2 of the new shape. This follows standard Python rules for negative indexing: -1 is the last element, -2 is the second-to-last, etc. Note that this is relative to the *new* shape, not the old shape; index -2 of the new shape is index -1 of the old shape.